# How to print to a Lexmark 5630 printer using CUPS

Tags: printing, cups

I want to print using a Lexmark 5630 printer, and [it appears](http://support.lexmark.com/index?locale=en&page=product&productCode=LEXMARK_X5630&segment=SUPPORT&userlocale=EN_US&frompage=null#1) they only have drivers for Mac and Windows. Does CUPS support it, with maybe some reverse-engineered driver, or am I at a loss?

Comment: The web site support.lexmark.com currently lists "Printer driver for 32-bit Linux distributions with Debian-based packaging".

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at the [Open Printing](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Lexmark/Lexmark-5000) website.